# Can Schauder's fixed point theorem apply to a metric space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fixed-point-theorems

I am currently reading the existence proof of Mean Field Game equation, which is a coupled system of Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation and Fokker-Planck equation, see page 42 of the paper [here](https://math.stanford.edu/~ryzhik/STANFORD/MEAN-FIELD-GAMES/notes-mean-field.pdf).  The idea is to obtain a fixed point of a continuous mapping $\Psi: S \mapsto S$. The space $S$ is given by $C([0, T], \mathcal P(\mathbb T))$, where $P(\mathbb T))$ is Wasswerstein metric space. 
The proof is closed up with [Schauder's FPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_fixed-point_theorem), which is usually applied for Banach space. I am not sure this generalization can be found in any literature?

Comment: I guess $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb T)$ is treated as a closed convex subspace of the space of finite signed measures on $\mathbb{T}$ endowed with the weak*-topology. The set $S$ is only a subset of the space you described. As the Wikipedia entry, you linked to, states, the  fixed-point argument works in any local convex Hausdorff topological vector space.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks for your reply. Yes, I agree with you. It seems to work for much more general setup from Wiki.